# Живой поиск на Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Реально ли организовать живой поиск на KivyMD?
Например:

- в текстовое поле ввожу данные;
- эти данные делают запрос на сервер;
- в формате `json` возвращается список, который мне надо вывести на экран с возможностью выбора

Comment: onkeyup там должен быть метод..

Comment: нашел только on_touch_up и on_touch_down